# Why isn't anything being saved to my character array?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I'm trying to ask a user to enter a string of characters. I want my program to continue scanning in the characters one at a time until it sees the `\n` character (i.e., when the user presses the ENTER key).

It appears that the code I've written doesn't store the characters to the array for some reason. I know this because the `for` loop containing the `printf()` statement doesn't reproduce the characters that are entered into the terminal. My last ditch effort was to print out `a[0]` in case something was going wrong with my loop, but it still showed that nothing was stored to my character array.

Any explanations? (Please don't suggest that I use the `string.h` library--I do not wish to use it for my purposes.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char a[21];

  int i;

  printf("enter a bunch of characters: ");

  for (i = 0; ; i++)
    {
      scanf("%c", &a[i]);
      if (a[i] = '\n')
        {
          break;
        }
    }

  printf("the size of char array is %d\n", sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));

  for (i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
      printf("%c", a[i]);
    }

  printf("%c", a[0]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second `for` loop looks for `a[i] != '\0'`, but you never put a null byte into the array.

Comment: typo: `if (a[i] = '\n')` assigns `'\n'`  to `a[i]`, and evaluates to "true". Then we immediately exit the loop. You mean to say `if (a[i] == '\n')`

Comment: Aha! Thank you for pointing that out @PaulRoub. What a rookie mistake for me to make. And @Barmar, I didn't realize I had to do that myself. I thought the `\0` automatically went to the last element in the area when it's declared?

Comment: Automatic variables are not initialized with any specific values. Global and static variables are automatically initialized to all 0.

Comment: The `for` loop should limit the number of characters, i.e. `for (i=0; i<20; i++)` so that the user can't overrun the buffer. Also, your compiler should have issued a warning about the typo. If it didn't, you need to use a higher warning level.

Comment: I like to put my relational expressions the other way around to avoid this mistake.  So, you could do if ('\n' == a[i]) { and the compiler would flag it for you as an error.  Modern gcc has a warning for this: -Wparentheses.

Comment: I'm using gcc in UNIX, and it didn't produce an error. I didn't realize I needed to use options with gcc :(

Comment: @gabacabriel Are you sure it didn't generate a warning? If not, try again with `-Wall`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a[i] == '\n') { break; }
```

Modify if statement as above and check.